# How to make Load More button not show if less than 8 posts

Tags: jquery, dom, lazy-loading

I have a landing blog page with load more function. I set up 12 posts to show on load, the problem is that if there are less than 12 (only 7 posts published), the Load More button will be still displayed and it will disappear only on click on it. Any ideas how to modify this code in order to have Load More button not show if less than 12 posts present on the page?

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(document).find(".ajaxsingnews").slice(0, 12).show();
    $("#loadMore").click(function() {
      $(".ajaxsingnews:hidden").slice(0, 12).slideDown();
      if ($(".ajaxsingnews").length) {
        $("#loadMore").hide();
      }
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

I expect Load More button not to be displayed if less than 12 posts present on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for length of `.ajaxsingnews` nodes:

```
  $(function() {
    const $newsNodes = $(".ajaxsingnews");
    if ($newsNodes.length < 12) {
      $("#loadMore").hide();
    } else {
      $("#loadMore").show();
    }

    // Rest of the code
  });
```